# rpy2, package 'outliers' functions not working

Tags: python, r, rpy2, outliers

I have a problem with almost all functions from R`s package: outliers.
The "choosen one" function which working correctly is outliers

```
list_ = ['chisq.out.test','cochran.test', 'dixon.test', 
         'grubbs.test', 'outlier',  'qcochran']
y = some data without brackets like 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.48416666667,
for f in list_:
try:
    code = """ y=c({0});
           require(outliers);
           {1}(y);""".format(y, f)
```

I received message:

> could not find function "complete.cases"

I tried also:

```
y = FloatVector([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.48416666667, 0.48716666667])
outliers = importr('outliers')
outliers.outlier(y) //works
outliers.cochran.test(y) //not working -> syntax is different
```

Do you have any suggestions, how can I solve that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, the "dot" can be used in variable names. It cannot in Python.

`importr` is trying to help with this as described here:
http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_rpackages.html